# Why 'checkout master' takes longer than 'checkout feature-branch'?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-checkout

I've just noticed, sometimes when switching between master and feature-branch,
even when everything is already pulled/pushed + up-to-date...

If I do

```
git checkout featureBranch
```

it is instant (and no progress info).

But when I do

```
git checkout master
```

It takes longer, and you also get progress info:

```
Checking out files: 100% (312/312), done.
```

And this behaviour is repeatable even when I just switch back and forth several times.

Just curious -- What's the underlying implementation-detail(?) that causes this?

Answer (score 2):

**Update** - torek points out (in comments) that git runs out a timer before it starts showing status - so quick checkouts don't show status at all, but if it starts taking long enough you might notice, you can see progress.  Updated a few words to reflect that.

---

At some level I'd say this must be something to do with the particular repo, as I'm not aware of any ways (other than "being the default name of the first branch") that git considers `master` special as branches go.

But I can make an educated guess.  When there are packed objects, git optimizes for the latest version of any given file.  For example, say you have

```
A --- B --- C <--(master)
             \
              D <--(feature)
```

Every file in `D` will be "the latest version" of that particular file; so either it's a loose object, or its a "non-diff" object in a pack file.  So checking out `feature` doesn't have to patch any files; it just reads the blobs.  It can happen fast enough that git doesn't feel the need to start showing status.

In theory `C` could have "older versions" of some files, that could be represented as "diff from *newer-version-of-file*" in a pack.  In practice, with just one newer commit in your active branch, I doubt it would come to that.  But in a real repo, where `master` might be behind `develop` and `develop` might be behind any number of feature branches, it's not unlikely that the `master` head commit has some packed-and-diffed objects to resolve.  I suspect the application of patches is what takes enough time for visible status reports to be given.

It's not the only *possible* explanation.  Maybe you have a bigger work tree under `master`, or maybe usage of LFS would be a factor (though I think you'd see different output in that case).  Like I said, generally I'd suspect repo-specific factors to be at play.  It's just that what I described above is a "repo-specific factor" that probably applies to most non-trivial repos.

---

**Update 2** - My underlying claim here - that `master` is not special - is pretty easy to test.  Clone the repo, and in the clone

```
git checkout master
git branch featureOldMasterBranch
git checkout featureBranch
git branch -f master
```

And now, within the clone checkout of `master` should be instant while checkout of `featureOldMasterBranch` should take enough time to show visible progress updates.

Remembering that a branch is just a ref is just a pointer, this demonstrates that it's something different about the commits - i.e. something repo-specific - and not any special handling of `master`.

Comment: I don't know who down-voted this, or why, but without the actual repository and work-tree, it's about the best we can say. Though I would add that the "checking out files ... (m/n)" parts come out after a timer fires off, so *that* at least is simply because checking out master is slower.

Comment: Thanks, @torek.  I wasn't aware of the timer; updated a bit.